# Parse result of batch command output in windows

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file

I just want to know how we can parse the batch command output. The following one is the small example where Iam trying to get the service name.

```
C:\Users\pande\Desktop>sc qdescription "test"
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: test
DESCRIPTION:  C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\small.exe /service
```

Here the question is , from the above result I want to hold the below part as a batch file variable.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\
```

By goggling we can achieve this by **for /f**, but really don't know how I can get it.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "DESC="
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=: " %%a IN ('sc qdescription "bonjour service" ') DO (
 IF "%%a"=="DESCRIPTION" SET "desc=%%b"
)
ECHO DESC=%DESC%

:: Setting DESC to the string expected - then ECHOing to prove

SET "DESC=C:\Program Files (x86)\TEST\small.exe /service"
ECHO DESC=%DESC%

:: Now remove part past '/' and select drive/path from assumed filename

FOR /f "tokens=1delims=/" %%a IN ("%desc%") DO SET "desc=%%~dpa"
ECHO DESC=%DESC%

:: Now remove terminal "\"

SET "desc=%desc:~0,-1%"
ECHO DESC=%DESC%

:: Extension - to remove the last "leaf" directoryname
::
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%desc%") DO SET "desc=%%~dpa"
ECHO DESC=%DESC%

:: Now remove new terminal "\"

SET "desc=%desc:~0,-1%"
ECHO DESC=%DESC%

GOTO :EOF
```

You'd need to save this text in a file named `whateveryoulike`**.bat** then run it as `whateveryoulike` from the command-prompt.

I used an installed service on my machine since I don't have access to yours. You would need to substitute your servicename in place of `bonjour service` above.

I then set `desc` to the value you show you are getting, and then how to process it down to the portion you require.

---

Modified to remove the last directoryname leaf.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for your valuable reply.This is what Am looking for.

Comment: Hi Magoo, small doubt that if I want to get only "C:\Program Files (x86)" what should I do.Please reply.